# dotNetNuke/Moodle integration

Tags: dotnetnuke, single-sign-on, moodle

anyone out there have a moodle module for dotnetnuke, or some kind of integration setup that at least allows SSO?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

***[This webpage](http://dotnetnuke.montreat.edu/SingleSignon/tabid/727/Default.aspx)***  provides details on how to implement Single Sign-on between DotNetNuke and Moodle.